# Will the sprite be automatically not drawn when outside the Camera's view in Libgdx (Android)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When using camera.translate(-x,-y) method, does it automatically not draw the sprites outside it's view or do I have to do it manually not to draw the sprites outside the camera's view?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the stage, it does that for you:

From the Libgdx API, Groups draw method:

Draws all children. applyTransform(Batch, Matrix4) should be called before and resetTransform(Batch) after this method if transform is true. If transform is false these methods don't need to be called, children positions are temporarily offset by the group position when drawn. **This method avoids drawing children completely outside the culling area, if set**.

So without the stage you need to do this manually.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... But I am not using stage and I directly draw the sprite into the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is drawn, but the GPU overhead will be lower because it doesn't have to run the fragment shader on any fragments for that sprite. CPU overhead will be the same.

Whether it makes sense to manually check sprites and cull ones outside the camera frustum depends on how many you can do at once. If you have to manually check each individual sprite, it likely is not worth it because you'll be spending about as much CPU overhead checking them as you would drawing them off screen. But if you can check groups of them quickly, then it may be worth it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using i.e a standard Orthographic camera and not doing anything overly funky with it (other than translating), then it should do this automatically. But it may depend on exactly how everything is set up.

To be sure, you can always try testing performance when drawing ridiculous numbers of sprites inside and outside of the room.

There's also ScissorStack;
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping%2C-with-the-use-of-scissorstack